# Does the Cauchy-Binet theorem simplify for matrices AWB, where W is a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, matrix-equations

Suppose I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$. The Cauchy-Binet theorem gives a way to calculate $\det(AB)$:
$$\det(AB) = \sum_S\det(A_S)\det(B_S),$$
where the sum is over all length-$m$ subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, $A_S$ is the $m\times m$ matrix whose columns are the columns in $A$ with indices $S$, and $B_S$ is the $m\times m$ matrix whose rows are the rows in $B$ with indices $S$.

Now suppose I have a square $n\times n$ matrix $W$. Is there a comparatively simple way to calculate $\det(AWB)$? It would be extra convenient if there is an expression for this in terms of $\det W$, so it could be extended to $N$ square matrices, something like $\det(A\prod_k^NW_kB)$.

I expected to find a corollary to the Cauchy-Binet theorem for linear transformations but haven't come across anything. Maybe it's obvious and my linear algebra is just too rusty?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to math SE. Can you please state Cauchy Binet theorem?

Comment: I've edited the question to include that and hopefully be a little clearer.

Comment: You could use the fact that $\bigwedge^m(AWB)=\bigwedge^m A\circ\bigwedge^m W\circ\bigwedge^m B$.

Comment: @blargoner Can you be more specific and/or dumb it down? You're already in an area that's way, way outside of my comfort zone.

Comment: @JohnHyatt I believe that if $W_S$ denotes the matrix whose rows **and** columns are taken from $W$ corresponding to the indices in $S$, then we have
$$
\det(AWB) = \sum_S \det(A_S)\det(W_S)\det(B_S)
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I just tested this numerically for $(m,n)=(2,3)$ (only 3 terms in the sum) and it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @JohnHyatt Makes sense. The trick I was remembering was one that applies when $W$ is diagonal but not in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general statement of Cauchy-Binet says that if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times p$, then
$$(AB)_{IJ}=\sum_K A_{IK}B_{KJ}$$
where $(AB)_{IJ}$ denotes the minor determinant of $AB$ with rows indexed from $I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and columns indexed from $J\subseteq\{1,\ldots,p\}$, with $I$ and $J$ of same size. In the sum, $K$ ranges over all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of the same size as $I$ and $J$. Note if $m=p$ and $I=J=\{1,\ldots,m\}$, then this reduces to the version you stated.

In the language of exterior algebra, this result is equivalent to functoriality of $k$-th exterior powers, whose entries are $k\times k$ minors:
$$\textstyle\bigwedge^k(AB)=\bigwedge^k A\circ\bigwedge^k B$$

This extends to more than two matrices, so if $m=p$ and $W$ is $n\times n$, then
$$\textstyle\bigwedge^m(AWB)=\bigwedge^m A\circ\bigwedge^m W\circ\bigwedge^m B$$
The left hand side here is a $1\times 1$ matrix consisting of the single entry $\det(AWB)$, while the right hand side is a product of:

- the $1\times\binom{n}{m}$ matrix of $m\times m$ minors of $A$
- the $\binom{n}{m}\times\binom{n}{m}$ matrix of $m\times m$ minors of $W$
- the $\binom{n}{m}\times 1$ matrix of $m\times m$ minors of $B$

**Example:** if
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}9&2&2\\1&8&0\end{bmatrix}\qquad W=\begin{bmatrix}1&4&2\\1&1&0\\1&3&1\end{bmatrix}\qquad B=\begin{bmatrix}6&4\\0&9\\5&5\end{bmatrix}$$
then
$$AWB=\begin{bmatrix}178&548\\64&154\end{bmatrix}$$
so
$$\det(AWB)=-7660$$

The compound matrices of $2\times 2$ minors are:
$$\textstyle\bigwedge^2 A=\begin{bmatrix}70&-2&-16\end{bmatrix}\qquad\bigwedge^2 W=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-2&-2\\-1&-1&-2\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix}\qquad\bigwedge^2 B=\begin{bmatrix}54\\10\\-45\end{bmatrix}$$
the product of which is
$$\begin{bmatrix}-7660\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!